# Is BufferedReader ignoring the first line?

Tags: java, telnet, bufferedreader

I am currently writing a service that should take cleartext commands and then return something according to thoose commands, which is also in cleartext.

I have this odd problem with `BufferedReader`, or, it might be telnet that is odd, for some reason the `BufferedReader` reads the first command, however that command is ignored no matter what i do, which i can get around by sending the first command twice, but that is just stretching it a bit, in my oppinion.

The code below is in a `run()` method.
Then i set `out` as a `PrintWriter` and `in` as a `BufferedReader`.
The `runs` variable is by default `true`.

```
out = new PrintWriter(handle.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(handle.getInputStream()));
while (runs) {
    String msg;
    msg = in.readLine();
    String[] command;
    command = msg.split(" ", 3);
    /* do something with the command */
}
```

So my question is if `BufferedReader` is ignoring the first line or is it telnet that is not coorperating with me?

If it is something else, then please enlighten me.

**EDIT**
I got this debug message:

Debug: ���� ����'������/nick halmark

so i suppose that it is about all the questionmarks.

Comment: You're definitely right to dig in and figure out what's causing the problem, rather than just working around it.  There's a reason it's happening somewhere.

Comment: I have been looking far and wide in Netbeans, and on the web, for a solution on the problem, but i have failed to find the answer.

Comment: At the very least you should print / log out the successive values of msg to see if that gives you some clues.

Comment: Judging from the code sample, I'd say that part is correct. So it leave what's around it. Are you sure you're not sharing the `in` variable across threads for example? or worse, the `handle` socket?

Comment: @mprivat I am parsing down the `handle` variable in the right maner, and it not used anywhere else, besides i have a thread with the `ServerSocket` where it waits for incomming connections and is set there, after someone connects to the service, then i create a new thread with the socket as a parameter, however, i am only using it in the working thread, and nowhere else, because there will be a new variable/overwriten in the previous thread

Comment: @SJuan76 i could do that, it would make sense to do so

Comment: what version of telnet are you using to connect to this java program?

Comment: Looks like an issue with encoding, Google says telnet uses ASCII NVT and usually Java uses UTF-8 by default. The question would be then why the following commands are understood.

Comment: @JonLin I am actually using the latest Putty since i am developing on a windows box... and as far as i recall... then it does not exist by default.

Comment: @SJuan76 I see... so in theory i could just change the encoding, since i am using the latest Putty... I have to try that one out. On a side note, then most of the english characters are at the same place wether you use ansi or utf-8, however i noticed in earlier time that a clean use of utf-8 prepends some characters, i have to check that one out, but it is possible that this problem is due to that.

Comment: @SJuan76 I found out the problem... apparently i booted up a Linux and started up telnet... it connects fine and no problems with prepend of characters... in essense it is Putty that messed with the data string after connection has been made, since it works fine under Linux. Thanks folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am actually using the latest Putty since i am developing on a windows box... and as far as i recall... then it does not exist by default

If you are using PuTTY, you need to choose the **"Raw"** Connection Type.

Microsoft telnet servers like to have some content/protocol negotiation at the beginning, so PuTTY will do this by default as [per the RFC 854 spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html). That's the garbage that you are reading.

Comment: I should have known that, how come that Linux does not use these characters, or rather the telnet client?

Comment: @RalphAndreasen I don't know why, can't even give an uneducated guess other than it probably has something to do with content negotiation, and one tries to do it by default and the other doesn't.